# How to change expression of variable in output

Tags: variable

I run the example：

```
c = a - b;
e^(a - b)
```

This gives me e^(a-b).
How can I do to let it output e^c

Comment: maybe `e^(a - b) // FullSimplify[#, c == Defer[c]] &`?

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Try this: `(e^(a - b)) /. a -> c + b`. Have fun!